# Does any one has idea to install Opencv in spyder?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import cv2

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Please provide some more context for this, we can’t do much with only a 3 line error message.

Answer (score 0):

Install Anaconda

Install OpenCV-Python to Anaconda

The following instruction works for me is inspired by this OpenCV Youtub video. So far I have got it working on both my Desktop and Laptop. Both 64-bit machines and Windows 8.1.

Download OpenCV Package
Firstly, go to the official OpenCV site to download the complete OpenCV package. Pick a version you like (2.x or 3.x). I am on Python 2.x and OpenCV 3.x - mainly because this is how the OpenCV-Python Tutorials are setup/based on.

Copy and Paste the cv2.pyd file
The Anaconda Site-packages directory (e.g. C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages in my case) contains the Python packages that you may import. Our goal is to copy and paste the cv2.pyd file to this directory (so that we can use the import cv2 in our Python codes.).

To do this, copy the cv2.pyd file...

From this OpenCV directory (the beginning part might be slightly different on your machine):

## Python 2.7 and 32-bit machine:

C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x84

## Python 2.7 and 64-bit machine:

C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x64
To this Anaconda directory (the beginning part might be slightly different on your machine):

C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages
After performing this step we shall now be able to use import cv2 in Python code. BUT, we still need to do a little bit more work to get FFMPEG (video codec) to work (to enable us to do things like processing videos.)

Set Enviromental Variables
Right-click on "My Computer" (or "This PC" on Windows 8.1) -> left-click Properties -> left-click "Advanced" tab -> left-click "Environment Variables..." button.

Add a new User Variable to point to the OpenCV (either x86 for 32-bit system or x64 for 64-bit system.) I am currently on a 64-bit machine.

32-BIT OR 64 BIT MACHINE?   VARIABLE    VALUE
32-bit  OPENCV_DIR  C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12
64-bit  OPENCV_DIR  C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12
Append %OPENCV_DIR%\bin to the User Variable PATH.

For example, my PATH user variable looks like this...

Before:

C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda;C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Scripts
After:

C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda;C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Scripts;%OPENCV_DIR%\bin
This is it we are done! FFMPEG is ready to be used!

Test to confirm
We need to test whether we can now do these in Anaconda (via Spyder IDE):

Import OpenCV package
Use the FFMPEG utility (to read/write/process videos)
Test 1: Can we import OpenCV?
To confrim that Anaconda is now able to import the OpenCV-Python package (namely, cv2), issue these in the IPython Console:

import cv2
print cv2.**version**
If the package cv2 is imported ok with no errors, and the cv2 version is printed out, then we are all good! Here is a snapshot:

import-cv2-ok-in-anaconda-python-2.png

Test 2: Can we Use the FFMPEG codec?
Place a sample input_video.mp4 video file in a directory. We want to test whether we can:

read this .mp4 video file, and
write out a new video file (can be .avi or .mp4 etc.)
To do this we need to have a test python code, call it test.py. Place it in the same directory as the sample input_video.mp4 file.

This is what test.py may look like (Note: many thanks to Pete's and Warren's suggestions in the comment field - I have replaced my original test code with his - please test it yourself and let us know if this works better):

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("input_video.mp4")
print cap.isOpened()   # True = read video successfully. False - fail to read video.

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output_video.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (640, 360))
print out.isOpened()  # True = write out video successfully. False - fail to write out video.

cap.release()
out.release()
This test is VERY IMPORTANT. If you'd like to process video files, you'd need to ensure that Anaconda / Spyder IDE can use the FFMPEG (video codec). It took me days to have got it working. But I hope it would take you much less time! :)

Note: one more very important tip when using the Anaconda Spyder IDE. Make sure you check the Current Working Directory (CWD)!!!

Next step
Now that we have the OpenCV-Python package (cv2), a potential good next step may be to checkout the OpenCV-Python Tutorials.

Comment: It's time to learn "How to format your post". It will help others to understand it well.